# syntax error, unexpected '$model' (T_VARIABLE) form yii2

Tags: php, yii

I'm beginner to learn yii2.

I am getting this error:

> syntax error, unexpected '$model' (T_VARIABLE) form yii2

Here is my code:

```
public function actionForms(){
    $model = new form11();  // <<error on this line
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');
```

Comment: The code you've posted looks fine, so the issue may be before that code. Are you using an IDE, such as Netbeans or PhpStorm? If not, get one installed and paste your code in - it will help you find your error.

Comment: it's a syntax error, but the declaration is ok at this point. See if any of these cases are happenning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them/18092267#18092267

Comment: i copy example form (https://www.cloudways.com/blog/creating-contact-form-in-yii2/ )

Comment: You have some missed closing / open  { }  ...eg :  you must check for right opne closing bracked in your functions declaration ..

Answer (score 0):

Check two things ...

1. You have created model named **form11** in `/models` directory. (With name space)
2. Include that model in this controller file.